# Extend method creating additional empty rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using .extend on a master table object (mastertbl) and looping so it grabs the objects from 3 different temp tables (with different object data type cols). I noticed that it is creating empty rows, for example, only 1 of the tables has data and the other 2 tables doesn't. So when I return mastertbl, it has 3 empty rows. How do you prevent it from adding empty rows?

```
   For list_obj in (select coalesce(tab.name,tab1.name,tab2.name) name, 
    tab1.location location, tab2.eduhist eduhist, tab.purchases purchases
    from tab full join tab1 on tab1.name = tab.name
     full join tab2 on tab2.name = tab1.name)
   Loop var_comp.extend;
   n := n+1
   var_listc(n) := mastertbl(list_obj.name, list_obj.location, list_obj.eduhist, list_obj.purchases)
   End loop;
```

Output

```
                             tab1            tab2            tab
        Name(varchar2)  LOCATION(obj)   EDUHIST(obj)    PURCHASES(obj)   
    1   Carol           Some_object                 
    2   -------------------------EMPTY ROW---------------------------
    3   -------------------------EMPTY ROW---------------------------
    4   -------------------------EMPTY ROW---------------------------
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a syntactically valid query that you have tested against your sample data that generates the issue you are trying to resolve (your query is not syntactically valid as you select from a table that does not exist); and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not work as you try to `SELECT tab3.purchases` but you never join to a `tab3` table.

I assume that you are getting the `NULL` values because you have values in the `tab` table but no corresponding values in `tab1`, `tab2` or `tab3`. Or maybe a `name` in `tab3` but no value in the `purchases` column. Without some sample data that replicates the problem and a syntactically valid query it is difficult to tell.

If your sample data appears to match that case then, check that at least one of the `OUTER JOIN`ed columns `IS NOT NULL`:

```sql
SELECT mastertbl(
         COALESCE(tab.name, tab1.name, tab2.name),
         tab1.location,
         tab2.eduhist,
         tab.purchases
       )
BULK COLLECT INTO var_listc
FROM   tab 
       FULL OUTER JOIN tab1
       ON tab.name = tab1.name
       FULL OUTER JOIN tab2
       on tab.name = tab2.name
 WHERE  tab.name IS NOT NULL
 OR     tab1.name IS NOT NULL
 OR     tab2.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, there is no tab3.. I'll edit that out.  In this case tab is the one is empty, so I cannot use LEFT or RIGHT outer joins , since I don't know which temp tables will be empty

Comment: @BFF In which case, use exactly the same technique as I describe in the answer with your `FULL OUTER JOIN`s (rather than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s) and just add the `WHERE` filter to check that one of the columns you want `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, I did Full Outer Joins and added the WHERE clause. It does return the correct values when run just straight query and does not include the empty rows BUT when it's using the .extend loop and I'm returning the mastertbl object, it still adds the 3 empty rows. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @BFF Use `BULK COLLECT INTO` rather than a loop.